# "Error: expected a type" when defining a method using CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-location

I'm trying to make a static method that takes in 2 `CLLocationCoordinate2D` parameters and returns the distance between them (using the Haversine formula). This is how it is defined in the interface:

```
+ (CGFloat)haversineDistanceFromCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)point1 toCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)point2;
```

However, when building I get 2 errors on that line saying "Expected a type", one for each mention of CLLocationCoordinate2D. Also, in the implementation of that method I get 2 warnings (again, one for each parameter) saying `Conflicting parameter types in implementation of haversineDist...: 'id' vs 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'`. When I command-click on CLLocationCoordinate2D in either the implementation or the interface, I get to the correct definition (in CoreLocation.framework). I've looked for any circular references (there are only 3 imports in the header file, one of them is the subclass and the other 2 are protocols implemented by my class). Is there anything else that could be going on?

Comment: Have you added the Core Location framework and imported it?  Also, why not use CLLocation's distanceFromLocation method?

Comment: It turns out I wasn't importing the CoreLocation framework. It's strange though - I've been using CLLocationCoordinate2D all over this app and haven't imported the CoreLocation framework in any other files. Also, the reason I'm rolling my own method is because I'm dealing with raw coordinates, rather than CLLocation objects. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It's easy to create a CLLocation object, it has an init method that takes latitude and longitude.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise - I thought you had to specify accuracy and a load of other stuff. Thanks!